# How to adjoin least significant bits to form a character in Java?

Tags: java, binary, byte, shift, steganography

I have a color array (read from a bmp file in case you wondered) that I take the least significant bits of each RGB value and create a pixels array.

Then I take that array and create a character out of each set of 8 elements, that I then add to a String called message.

Somewhere here my code malfunctions, and I do not get the output expected. Since I print out essentially all the pixels, I am unfortunately not able to provide the output.

Please tell me if you need in any clarifications.

```
// extracts a message hidden in a BMP file
public String extractMessage()
{
    int iter = 0;
    // read the lsbs of the rgb values into one array
    char[] pixels = new char[bmpHeight * bmpWidth * 3];
    for(Color[] cRow: image)
        for(Color c: cRow)
        {
            pixels[iter++] = c.getRed() & 1;   // make zero or one
            pixels[iter++] = c.getGreen() & 1;
            pixels[iter++] = c.getBlue() & 1;
        }

    // iterate through the pixels and move the lsbs into the correct place value
    String message = "";
    int i = 0;
    while(i < pixels.length - pixels.length % 8)
    {
        char c = (char)0;
        c += pixels[i++] << 7; // 1
        c += pixels[i++] << 6; // 2
        c += pixels[i++] << 5; // 3
        c += pixels[i++] << 4; // 4
        c += pixels[i++] << 3; // 5
        c += pixels[i++] << 2; // 6
        c += pixels[i++] << 1; // 7
        c += pixels[i++]; // 8
        message += c;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Update: Here is a sample file 3x2.bmp in a hex editor. I tried to hide the letter "c". https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH2ty.jpg

Comment: Give us your image and at least *part of* your expected output.

Comment: Break up your method into each of it's component functions, then write a test case for each function.

Comment: Works fine for me: [**See here**](http://ideone.com/ZLOIWb)

Comment: Why not just `c = ( pixels[i++] << 7 ) | ( pixels[i++] << 6 ) |...`?

Comment: You could use a `StringBuilder` to build the message... Otherwise though, sample data (input/output) would be of help here, just as @johnchen902 is asking for

Comment: Update with some hex editor screenshots. @johnchen902 I have a feeling it might be my encoding algorithm that is off.

Comment: I would appreciate if you took a look-see at the encoding algorithm. http://pastebin.com/meGygthD

Comment: @user1796994 The code you provided is working. Probably somewhere else go wrong. A fully working example (including reading and writing images): [link](http://ideone.com/I7GXvW)